# Retrieve value from modal form and update database php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Not sure if I'm going about this correctly but basically I'm trying to edit a row in a table using a modal. So far I've got 3 classes which are createUser.php which has the table and handles a request to retrieve the row and pass the data to getuser.php. This displays the modal and now I'm trying to retrieve the values from the modal form and update the database accordingly. This is what the `getuser.php` looks like atm:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

$("#edit-user").submit(function(e){

 e.preventDefault();

var uid = $('input[name="userid"]').val();
var username = $('input[name="username-update"]').val();
var password = $('input[name="password-update"]').val();
var role = $('input[name="role-update"]').val();

$.ajax({
  url: 'updateUser.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
  id : uid, 
  username: username,
  password: password, 
  role: role
  },
  dataType: 'html'
 })
 .done(function(data){
  console.log(data); 
  $('#update-username').html(data.username);
  $('#update-password').html(data.password);
  $('#update-role').html(data.role);
})

}); 

</script>   
 <?php

  require_once 'database.php';


if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {

 $id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid=:id";
 $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
 $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 extract($row);
  ?>

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content row">
            <div class="modal-header custom-modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Staff User Details</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">


                                <form name="info_form" class="form-inline" action="createUser.php" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="userid" id="update-id" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['id'] ?>">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                                <label>Username</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username-update" id="update-username" value="<?php echo $username ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                                <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password-update"  id="update-password" value="<?php echo $password ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="confirmpass" id="update-confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                    </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                                    <label>Role</label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" name="role-update" id="update-role" class="field-select">
                                                    <?php if($role == "staff"){ ?>
                                                    <option value="staff">Staff</option>
                                                    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                                    <option value="customer">Customer</option>
                                                    <?php }
                                                    else if($role == "admin") { ?>

                                                    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                                    <option value="staff">Staff</option>
                                                    <option value="customer">Customer</option>
                                                    <?php } else{ ?>
                                                    <option value="customer">Customer</option>
                                                    <option value="staff">Staff</option>
                                                    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                                    <?php } ?>

                                                    </select>
                                            </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="edit-user">Update</button>
                                                    <input type="hidden"    name="submit" value="TRUE" />
                    </div>

                </form>


                            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


<?php
 }
  ?>
```

Also I should mention that for some weird reason I've had to write that modal code twice (once in `createUser.php` and then again in `getuser.php`) otherwise the modal doesn't pop up. And this is the SQL code I have in `updateUser.php` which I'm hoping the data is sent to.

```
<?php

require_once 'database.php';

  if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
     $row = intval($_REQUEST['id']);
     $updateUsername = $_REQUEST['username'];
     $updatePassword = $_REQUEST['password'];
   //$confirmpass = $_REQUEST['confirmpassword'];
     $updateRole = $_REQUEST['role'];

     $query = "UPDATE users SET username=$updateUsername,   password=$updatePassword, role=$updateRole WHERE userid=$row ";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();


}


 ?>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Should also mention I'm learning something new here. Additionally, when I do check inspect element the Form Data is actually being sent on submit. Any help is much appreciated! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to send data as an object like this:

```
data: {
      id : uid, 
      username: username,
      password: password, 
      role: role
  }
```

I think your selectors are wrong too, try this:

```
 var uid = $('input[name="userid"]').val();
 var username = $('input[name="username-update"]').val();
 var password = $('input[name="password-update"]').val();
 var role = $('input[name="role-update"]').val();
```

Comment: I made the changes yet the actual database isn't being update, in the Form Data for inspect element when I send the request.. the actual data is there.. is there another way to retrieve that form data?

Comment: Can you please share the response you get in the network tab for this request?

Comment: Just checked there's nothing in the response but there's a call for updateUser.php and the form data included is:

id:5
username:Akeeb
password:Testing1234

The role (which is a drop down box <select>) isn't being send for some reason, When I click the Update button the modal remains open and I do see "updateUser.php" in the network tab. - Apologies for not being able to explain this any better.. :/ @FraserReid

Comment: I managed to get the drop down value now its just the actual pulling that data and using it in the query :/

Comment: Hey @FraserReid, I managed to figure it out.. Thanks for all your help buddy it was very much appreciated, I'm super grateful! :D